# C# - Loading dlls and creating instances

Tags: c#, dll, interface

I have a situation and I need to know how to deal with it in the best way.

I have an application (MVC3) and I have couple of integrations for it. I have an interface "IntegrationInterface" and every integration implements it.
I want to load the dlls of the integrations, create a list of them, and run a loop that runs a method for every integration in the list.

For example - let's say I have integrations for facebook, myspace and twitter (for my appliction), and every time the user post a message in my application I want to post a message  on his\her facebook, myspace and twitter.

I don't want that the code will know which integrations I have, so if tomorrow I'll create a new integration for google+,  I'll just need to add a new DLL without changing the code of my application.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you'll have to find all relevant dlls and classes:

```
loadedIntegrations.Clear();
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    return;
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.dll");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    Assembly newAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName);
    Type[] types = newAssembly.GetExportedTypes();
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        //If Type is a class and implements the IntegrationInterface interface
        if (type.IsClass && (type.GetInterface(typeof(IntegrationInterface).FullName) != null))
            loadedIntegrations.Add(type);
    }
}
```

`loadedIntegrations` is of type `List<Type>`. Then you can instantiate each integration and call its methods:

```
foreach(var integrationType in loadedIntegrations)
{
    var ctor = integrationType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
    var integration = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { }) as IntegrationInterface;
    //call methods on integration
}
```

Comment: The only risk here is that it will load any .dll file so there is risk of dropping there non managed dlls right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I assume, he is capable of including error handling to the necessary degree. But that depends on the exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar to what you described in an import utility that wrote.  My issue was that I didn't want to load ALL the assemblies.  I only wanted to load assemblies that contained types that were requested.

To accomplish this I've used the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event handler.

This event handler is raised just before the AppDomain throw an exception notifying that an assembly is not found.  I execute similar code to what Nico suggested in that handler and return the requested assembly.

NOTE: I have a sub-directory called 'Tasks' (think Import Tasks) where I store all of my assemblies I want to load at runtime.

Here is the code:

```
        var tasks = GetTasks();
        var basedir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // Get AppDomain Path
        var tasksPath = Path.Combine(basedir, "Tasks"); // append 'Tasks' subdir

        // NOTE: Cannot be factored, relies on 'tasksPath' variable (above).
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) => // defined 'AssemblyResolve' handler
        {
            var assemblyname = e.Name + ".dll"; // append DLL to assembly prefix
            // *expected* assembly path
            var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(tasksPath, assemblyname); // create full path to assembly
            if (File.Exists(assemblyPath)) return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath); // Load Assembly as file.
            return null; // return Null if assembly was not found. (throws Exception)
        };

        foreach (var task in tasks.OrderBy(q => q.ExecutionOrder)) // enumerate Tasks by ExecutionOrder
        {
            Type importTaskType = Type.GetType(task.TaskType); // load task Type (may cause AssemblyResolve event to fire)
            if (importTaskType == null)
            {
                log.Warning("Task Assembly not found");
                continue;
            }
            ConstructorInfo ctorInfo = importTaskType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes); // get constructor info
            IImportTask taskInstance = (IImportTask)ctorInfo.Invoke(new object[0]); // invoke constructor and cast as IImportTask
            taskInstances.Add(taskInstance);
        }
        // rest of import logic omitted...
```

Answer (score -1):

If u know MEF (Managed extensibility framework) this might help you I personally use it but have to say that using MEF with MVC is not trivial i think for more information please visit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx